# Decorating Items in custom ItemsControl, not with an ItemContainer

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, itemtemplate, itemcontainerstyle

I would like to create (the equivalent of) a custom `ItemsControl` where the `Item`s are placed in a `StackPanel`, intermingled with some other control, say a `Button`. So, I want the following to be equivalent in terms of the layout:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button>OK</Button>
    <TextBox>Hello</TextBox>
    <Button>OK</Button>
    <TextBox>World</TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

and

```
<CustomControlInQuestion>
    <TextBox>Hello</TextBox>
    <TextBox>World</TextBox>
</CustomControlInQuestion>
```

All of the alternative roads I've gone down (`ItemContainer`s, `ItemTemplate`s, custom `Panel`s) have failed to create quite this behavior. Is there any technique able to achieve this?

It's probably worth emphasizing that I really do need this to be a custom control :)

Thank you!

Comment: Just curious, what is the reason behind this and not organize Button + TextBox as one single item and let that be your DataTemplate for the ItemsControl

Comment: It's because I _really_ am interested in sticking these items as top-level elements of a Grid, and instead of Buttons, they would be GridSplitters.

I made the example a bit contrived to get at the heart of my question, because there are other issues with the Grid approach, so I hope this doesn't derail the topic :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am just giving a hint to achieve your requirement, If you are familiar with ItemTemplateSelector,
dataTemplate you can do this by yourself.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="PanelControl" ItemsSource="{Binding bindYourSourceHere}" 
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource bindYourItemTemplateSelector}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>


//StackPanel is set to ItemsControl.ItemsPanel
// Write a ItemTemplateSelector and write your own logic to select either button template or textbox template
// In case if I misunderstood your requirement, please let me know it in more detail.
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a starting point you, a mini implementation of vertical stack panel:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace TabControl1
{
    public class CustomControl1 : Panel
    {
        protected override Size MeasureOverride (Size availableSize)
        {
            Size panelDesiredSize = new Size (0, 0);

            foreach (UIElement child in this.InternalChildren)
            {
                var childMaxSize = new Size (double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
                child.Measure (childMaxSize);
                var v = (FrameworkElement)child;

                panelDesiredSize.Width += child.DesiredSize.Width;

                if (panelDesiredSize.Height < child.DesiredSize.Height)
                {
                    panelDesiredSize.Height = child.DesiredSize.Height;
                }
            }

            return panelDesiredSize;
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride (Size finalSize)
        {
            double x = 0;
            double y = 0;

            foreach (UIElement child in this.InternalChildren)
            {
                child.Arrange (new Rect (new Point (x, y), child.DesiredSize));

                x += child.DesiredSize.Width;
            }

            return finalSize; // Returns the final Arranged size
        }
    }
}
```